# Are component events documented?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If so, where?

For example, I'm surprised not to find any mention of `onFilled` and `onEmpty` in the doc page for `InputBase` or perhaps `FormControl`... not sure where these are coming from but they're not native HTML events.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't documented, then you should consider it an internal implementation detail of Material-UI.

For instance in [InputBase](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L505) you can find the following:

```
  /**
   * @ignore
   */
  onFilled: PropTypes.func,
```

The `@ignore` means that this is intentionally **not** documented. This means it is probably only for internal mechanisms for communicating information between components within Material-UI for supporting other documented features. It also means that it would not necessarily be considered a "breaking change" (i.e. it could change without a major version number change) if this property were removed or changed significantly since it is not part of the documented API.